# C++ Dynamically Define Function

Tags: c++, math, dynamic, methods, console

I am on visual c++ working on a console calculator, I am creating a way to let the user define a custom linear function. Here is where I am stumped: Once I get the users desired name of the function, the slope, and the y-intercept, I need to use that data to create a callable function that I can pass to muParser.

In muParser, you define custom functions like this:

```
double func(double x)
{
    return 5*x + 7; // return m*x + b;
}

MyParser.DefineFun("f", func);
MyParser.SetExpr("f(9.5) - pi");
double dResult = MyParser.Eval();
```

How could I dynamically create a function like this based on the users input for the values 'm' and 'b' and pass that to the 'DefineFun()' method?
This is what I have so far:

```
void cb_SetFunc(void)
{
    string FuncName, sM, sB;
    double dM, dB;
    bool GettingName = true;
    bool GettingM = true;
    bool GettingB = true;
    regex NumPattern("[+-]?(?:0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d+)?");

    EchoLn(">>> First, enter the functions name. (Enter 'cancel' to abort)");
    EchoLn(">>> Only letters, numbers, and underscores can be used.");

    try
    {
        do // Get the function name
        {
            Echo(">>> Enter name: ");
            FuncName = GetLn();
            if (UserCanceled(FuncName)) return;

            if (!ValidVarName(FuncName))
            {
                EchoLn(">>> Please only use letters, numbers, and underscores.");
                continue;
            }
            GettingName = false;

        } while (GettingName);

        do // Get the function slope
        {
            Echo(">>> Enter slope (m): ");
            sM = GetLn();
            if (UserCanceled(sM)) return;

            if (!regex_match(sM, NumPattern))
            {
                EchoLn(">>> Please enter any constant number.");
                continue;
            }
            dM = atof(sM.c_str());
            GettingM = false;

        } while (GettingM);

        do // Get the function y-intercept
        {
            Echo(">>> Enter y-intercept (b): ");
            sB = GetLn();
            if (UserCanceled(sB)) return;

            if (!regex_match(sB, NumPattern))
            {
                EchoLn(">>> Please enter any constant number.");
                continue;
            }
            dB = atof(sB.c_str());
            GettingB = false;

        } while (GettingB);

            // ------------
            // TODO: Create function from dM (slope) and
            // dB (y-intercept) and pass to 'DefineFun()'
            // ------------
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ErrMsg("An unexpected error occured while trying to set the function.");
    }
}
```

I was thinking that there isn't a way to define an individual method for each user-defined-function. Would I need to make a `vector<pair<double, double>> FuncArgs;` to keep track of the appropriate slopes and y-intercepts then call them dynamically from the function? How would I specify which pair to use when I pass it to `DefineFun(FuncStrName, FuncMethod)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need (in addition to a script language interpreter) is called a ["trampoline"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)). There is no standard solution to create those, in particular since it involves creating code at runtime.

Of course, if you accept a fixed number of trampolines, you can create them at compile time. And if they're all linear, this might be even easier:

```
const int N = 20; // Arbitrary
int m[N] = { 0 };
int b[N] = { 0 };
template<int I> double f(double x) { return m[I] * x + b; }
```

This defines a set of 20 functions `f<0>...f<19>` which use `m[0]...m[19]` respectively.

**Edit:**

```
// Helper class template to instantiate all trampoline functions.
double (*fptr_array[N])(double) = { 0 };
template<int I> struct init_fptr<int I> {
  static const double (*fptr)(double) = fptr_array[I] = &f<I>;
  typedef init_fptr<I-1> recurse;
};
template<> struct init_fptr<-1> { };
```

Comment: Which would be great, except that when muParser calls the function, it will not pass the `I` template parameter to the function to get the values at the specified index in `m` and `b`. I do not control how the function is called, muParser independently does that when it finds "f(x)" in the set expression string. Not to mention I would be passing a `template<int> double(double)` to a `double(double)` argument.

Comment: @BrandonMiller: You use it as `MyParser.DefineFun("foo", f<0>); MyParser.DefineFun("bar", f<1>); `. The C++ compiler will generate up to 20 unique addresses, and muParser will pass one of those addresses - not `I`.

Comment: Hmm! I think this is exactly what I need! It seems pretty simple and straight forward. boost::function's with all that 'bind', 'reference' and 'delegate' jargon confuses me. Going to try this right away. And this will be done at runtime, so instead of two arrays I'm thinking I should use a `vector<pair<double, double>> FuncArgs` and access them like `return FuncArgs.at(I).first * x + FuncArgs.at(I).second;`

Comment: @BrandonMiller: That would work as well, just keep in mind that you can't instantiate templates at runtime. If you mention `f<0>, f<1>, f<3>` at compile time, only those 3 functions would be instantiated. Editing...

Comment: I've hit a brick wall. I need to dynamically get the index of the function, but I can only use a constant value for indexes:
`pair<double,double> argPair;

  argPair.first = dM;

  argPair.second = dB;

  LinFuncArgs.push_back(argPair);

  int index = NCast<int,size_t>(LinFuncArgs.size());

  Calc->DefineFun(FuncName, LinFunc<index>);`
And at the last line I get the error: "Expression must have a constant expression". So I have to manually enter the index number, which totally defeats the purpose.

Comment: @BrandonMiller: See my latest update; use `fptr_array[index]`. Do initialize the array first with `init_fptr<N>()`.

Comment: Using your update, I am back at square-one. Now I have a container (function pointer array), but am confused on how to define the function to insert into the array.

Comment: @BrandonMiller: The array is already initialized; e.g. fptr_array[7] is f<7>. You just fill `LinFuncArgs` and change `f<I>` to use `LinFuncArgs[I]`

Comment: Well the problem is accessing `f<I>` without `I` being a constant number, rather than the current index in the `LinFuncArgs` vector. Here, maybe this paste will help clarify what's confusing me: http://pastebin.com/9VwQ3Yr1

Comment: How would I use your updates in that code? I'm not sure where the function array comes in, as with `f<I>` I dont need the array, just the vector I store my slope:intercept pairs in. Everything seemed like it'd work like a charm until I couldn't specify which index to pass to `f<I>` (which I've renamed `LinFunc<I>`)

Comment: @BrandonMiller: That's where you use `fptr_array`. See http://pastebin.com/tnbz0TFZ

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16638/discussion-between-msalters-and-brandon-miller)

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple:

```
#include <functional>

std::function<double(double)> f;   // this is your dynamic function

int slope, yintercept;             // populate from user input

f = [=](double x) -> double { return slope * x + yintercept; };
```

Now you can pass the object `f` to your parser, which can then call `f(x)` at its own leisure. The function object packages the captured values of `slope` and `yintercept`.

Comment: I believe OP wants to "dynamically create a function ... based on the users input". However maybe we shall ask if dynamically means during runtime or before compilation...

Comment: That will probably cause problems since the external math library wants a function pointer, which `std::function` is not.

Comment: The problem is there will be many of these functions with different slopes and y-intercepts. With only those two variables keeping track of them, once the user defines another function he will no longer be able to use the previous functions. There needs to be a list of these functions with different M's and B's that the user can call by typing func(7) + anotherFunc(9.53)

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Yes, I believe you are correct. I need there to be (I guess a vector) of these function pointers all with different slopes and intercepts in them

Comment: @BrandonMiller: You could trivially make a `std::vector<std::function<double(double)>>` and put all your different functions in there. The question is whether you're able to change the interface of the parser to accept `std::function` objects as its core primitive.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is there a way to 'resolve' the `std::function` type to the type specified in the template parameters?

Comment: @BrandonMiller: What do you mean by "resolve"? You can't put something in quotation marks (which indicate that the word has an unusual meaning) and then *not* explain the meaning! :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB What I mean is cast the `std::function<double(double)> f` to a `double f(double)` so I can pass it in `MyParser.DefineFun("f", f);`

Comment: @BrandonMiller: No, certainly not. Free functions don't have a state, but the function object in general has.

Comment: you cant 'resolve' a boost function to a function pointer.  You can get at its member function pointer and use it along with the 'this' pointer for the boost function to call it.  But you'll never call it as a function directly.  You could generate a vector of free function slots that each delegate to a boost::function but it is probably easier to rewrite the code that needs it to be a double f(double) so that it needs a boost::function instead!

Comment: @Pete Sounds like we're getting closer to a solution, but muParser is a rather large library and that seems like a daunting task to me. Perhaps I'll try this though, I will need to learn a bit more about boost:function's though. Ugh! This would be so much easier if you could define a function within another function and add it to a vector then pass it like `MyParser.DefineFun("f", FuncVector.at(i));`

Answer (score 1):

[GiNaC](http://www.ginac.de/) is C++ lib which can parse and evaluate math expressions.

Comment: Thanks, but that part is all under control. My calculator is fully functional in terms of evaluating expressions, I'm just seeking to enable the user to define their own linear functions for use in expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed to your application some script language. Years ago I was using Tcl for similar purpose - but I do not know what is the current time best choice.

Either you can start from Tcl or search yourself for something better:

See: [Adding Tcl/Tk to a C application](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3474)

Comment: [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) is popular these days, and _very_ easy to embed. It also has a very small footprint.

Comment: Another candidate: 'Chibi-Scheme is a very small library intended for use as an extension and scripting language in C programs.' http://code.google.com/p/chibi-scheme/

Comment: Also, Squirrel is a very nice language suitable for embedding in C/C++ apps, similar to Lua, but even better: http://www.squirrel-lang.org/

Comment: That's funny because originally to actually parse the mathematical equations I tried embedding TCL in my program, but I ran into problems with missing headers which I then tried to find online to no avail. So if I embed one of those languages I can simply create a string which defines my function and pass it to the embedded language parser and then pass the newly created function to the `DefineFun()` method? What about scope issues? I need the function to exist throughout my program so that my muParser instance can call it. When the function returns wont my new method be destroyed?

Comment: @Brandon: I believe many (or all) of these script languages provide functionality to "compile" script function once and then use it many times. Just look at the doc.

Comment: @BrandonMiller: You probably want a `std::map<std:string, LuaFunction>` somewhere in your program then. Such user-defined functions are C++ objects, and therefore follow the lifetime rules for objects. Your `muParser` can easily check whether the map has an entry for `"func"`

Comment: @MSalters When a user types in "func(5)" into the console, when I pass the expression string to muParser it immediately calls the function given in the second argument of `DefineFun()`, I have no say in the processing of that. It seems maybe I only need a `vector<LuaFunction>` to store the functions so that muParser can call them when it finds the function name string? Also the functions are of type `double(double)`, How would I go about casting a `LuaFunction` to a `typedef double (*muFunc)(double)`? Also the muParser actually uses templates, not my typedef, thats concept only.

Comment: @BrandonMiller: Ah, muParser already handles the name. Yes, then it's sufficient to just store the function without the associated name. The problem indeed lies in the casting.

Comment: @MSalters Also, I see that when you use Lua in C++, you must first define the C++ function and pass it to `lua_register(ls, "MyFunc", my_func)` and then it can be called in lua. I need it the other way around because the problem area is defining the function.

Comment: @MSalters But how do I define the function without doing it in C++ first? I cannot create a function within a function, I need the body of the function to reflect what values for 'm' and 'b' the user entered, but I cant just in the middle of `cb_SetFunc()` define `double FuncNameString(double x) { return dM*x + dB; }`

Comment: use function objects and bind the values in as member variables.  Either use boost::function (as suggested by others) to do this or use an interface and derive different functions from it so that you have a uniform interface.  If you absolutely must create a native (machine code) function with the scalar/offset as literal values then expect a lot of work and portability issues.  Or embed google v8 and define the function in javascript code and compile it.

Comment: @BrandonMiller: Basically, `cb_SetFunc()` converts the user input to Lua code (or just let the user enter Lua code) and pass that to `luaL_loadstring`. Your C++ function is outside `cb_SetFunc()` and uses `lua_call`

Answer (score 0):

Generating a fixed array of functions bindable to boost function.

Someone else already said about a similar method, but since I'd taken the time to write the code, here it is anyway.

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

enum {
    MAX_FUNC_SLOTS = 255
};

struct FuncSlot
{
    double (*f_)(double);
    boost::function<double(double)> closure_;
};

FuncSlot s_func_slots_[MAX_FUNC_SLOTS];

template <int Slot>
struct FuncSlotFunc
{
    static void init() {
        FuncSlotFunc<Slot-1>::init();
        s_func_slots_[Slot - 1].f_ = &FuncSlotFunc<Slot>::call;
    }
    static double call(double v) {
        return s_func_slots_[Slot - 1].closure_(v);
    }
};
template <> struct FuncSlotFunc<0> {
    static void init() {}
};

struct LinearTransform
{
    double m_;
    double c_;
    LinearTransform(double m, double c)
        : m_(m)
        , c_(c)
    {}
    double operator()(double v) const {
        return (v * m_) + c_;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FuncSlotFunc<MAX_FUNC_SLOTS>::init();

    s_func_slots_[0].closure_ = LinearTransform(1, 0);
    s_func_slots_[1].closure_ = LinearTransform(5, 1);

    std::cout << s_func_slots_[0].f_(1.0) << std::endl; // should print 1
    std::cout << s_func_slots_[1].f_(1.0) << std::endl; // should print 6

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So, you can get the function pointer with: s_func_slots_[xxx].f_
And set your action with s_func_slots_[xxx].closure_